# Как использовать protobuf в проекте

Tags: c++, шаблоны-проектирования, google-protobuf

Есть класс в котором определены методы, члены класса.
Для примера, пусть в классе хранятся такие члены:

```
std::map<int, std::string>
int
std::list<std::string>
```

Хочу сериализовать эти данные на диск, использую protobuf.
Для использования protobuf определяю файл .proto. Далее protoc сгенерирует мне pb.cc и pb.h , и там будут определены классы, в которых есть методы для сериализации, десериализации.

Как использовать сгенерированные классы:

1. Добавить set/get методы в мой класс и заполнять структуры
   сгенерированных классов посредством этих методов?
2. Или переписать логику моего класса в эти сгенерированные?

Comment: Поясните какого рода взаимодействие необходимо?

Comment: Класс строит определенную модель, которую потом надо будет использовать.  Уже написан класс, который строит эту модель. Структуры данных, которые он использует, пусть будут как наверху написано. Вопрос в том, как их сериализовать? То есть переписать логику класса в сгенерированные классы, или добавить set/get методы в мой класс и заполнять структуры сгенерированных классов посредством этих методов?

Comment: пожалуйста, добавте пояснения в ворос, коментарии не для этого

Answer (score 2):

Правило будет такое:
Не надо ничего изменять в генерируемом коде, так как при перегенерации все исправления будут удалены.Код должен быть максимально независим от перегенераций.